How to extend the parent theme styles from child theme
We are working on the child theme that inherits Magento/luma and I am trying to extend the styles from my child theme, unfortunately, it is throwing errors like some files are missing in my child theme but in Magento/blank it is working fine so I got confused about why the Luma theme cannot extend it from the child theme so if anyone knows please help me I don't get anything. and help me how to extend/override the luma theme styles.
and I'm attaching the screen of the error I got.


Seems like You are missing some static assets (fonts in this case) from parent theme. Copying them from Magento/luma/web/fonts to Your's theme 'web' directory should fix this particular problem.

You need to override all the Less files from the parent luma theme.
Here are the files you need to override in your theme:
vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\web\css\source

Copy all the files from the path listed above and add them to your theme's web folder.
your_theme->web->css->source
Then run the magento commands
php bin/magento s:up;
php bin/magento s:d:c;
php bin/magento s:s:d -f;
php bin/magento c:f

Let's us know if it's works

Once You will check error message You will see that Your solution won't help. Besides that Your suggestion about copying all the mentioned files doesn;t align with Adobe's best practices in terms of maintenance of own themes...
